# Hide only the default controller name from the URL

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

Is it possible to force Zend_Router to check the defaultController for it's Actions, and skip the controller name in the URL, if the action is in the default controller ?

ie.
/defaultControllerName/action/ -> /action/
/nonDefaultContorller/action/ -> /nonDefaultContorller/action/

If it's impossible what's the convention to handle this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Static routes can accomplish this but you'd have to add one for each of your actions in the index controller.

So mysite.com/add would go to the index controller add action.

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $frontcontroller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $frontcontroller->getRouter();

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('add', array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'add'));

    $router->addRoute('add',$route);
}
```